# Kotlin multiplatform work with Dynamic Delivery?

Tags: android, gradle, multi-module, kotlin-multiplatform

I am new to Kotlin multiplatform development for android, so I wanted to know how I can implement [dynamic feature  delivery](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/dynamic-delivery) using Kotlin mpp? Is this even possible?

Comment: Never took that under consideration but I guess we need to try it out and see. I believe it is doable through making the common code for each feature in its own Kotlin multiplatform library.

Comment: Looks like this is possible, check takahiro repo here: https://github.com/takahirom/dynamic-feature-with-kotlin-mpp/ accessing the Dynamice Feature still using reflection atm